# visual studio code ctrl + tab not working as it was used to

Tags: visual-studio-code, key-bindings

I used to have an old VSCode version, where i used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to navigate through recently opened tabs.

when i pressed the combination a dropdown will appear where i could see the recently opened tabs. Then, if i pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> again, it would cycle through those tabs.

Recently, I updated VSCode to a newer version. Now, if i press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> the dropdown appears like it used to. But, when i press it again, it doesn't cycle through tabs anymore. Instead, it will open the last tab that I've accessed.

I've tried :

- uninstalling
- reinstalling
- removing the setting an reinstalling the older version

But still, that <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> functionality seems gone. can you help me restore it?

Comment: `Ctrl+tab` cycles through the dropdown for me.  Do you have something else bound to `Ctrl+tab`?  Check to see that `Ctrl+tab` is bound to the command `workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker` in your keyboard shortcuts.  If it is not, set it so.

Comment: apparently i installed a plugin that conflicted the keybindings. it is fixed now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your keyboard shortcuts.  Find the command:

```
workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker
```

By default it is set to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, if yours is not, set it that keybinding by clicking on the `pencil icon` to the left of the command on hover and enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> into the dialog box.

That command should also be using the `when` clauses: `inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen`

Comment: that fixed it!!

Comment: It stopped working for me in version 1.42.0. I have even tried to put ctrl+tab as a keyboard shortcut of any other function and I found that visual is not getting that key combination, it only appears "Ctrl+" but not the "tab". Is there anyone experimenting this behaviour?

Comment: I have the same behaviour, just started, i am using VS Code on linux

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue open Visual Studio Code, you have to edit **keybindings.json**.

Use the Command Palette with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, enter `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`, and hit Enter.

> Then add this to the end of the file:

```
[
    // ...
    {
    "key": "ctrl+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.nextEditor"
    },
    {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
    "command": "workbench.action.previousEditor"
    }
]
```

And also make sure that there's no other command used by this combination that may be blocking the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

To complete [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55998178/145599) above, search for all the commands with the combination `Ctrl+Tab` (you can do so by clicking on the keyboard icon at the search bar and then doing `Ctrl+Tab`), and make sure there's no other command used by this combination that may be blocking the one you need.

If you find one, remove its key binding using the right click menu or by clicking the pencil.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by opening `keybindings.json` (by default you can open this with `ctrl+shift+p` -> `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)`)

I first removed all pre-existing items with `{ "key": "ctrl+tab" }` or `{ "key": "ctrl+shift+tab" }`, and I then appended to the file:

```
[
    ... all other keybindings ...
    {
      "key": "ctrl+shift+tab",
      "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigatePreviousInEditorPicker",
      "when": "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen"
    },
    {
      "key": "ctrl+tab",
      "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInEditorPicker",
      "when": "inEditorsPicker && inQuickOpen"
    }
]
```