# Ctrl + tab suddenly stopped working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I already checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55997552/visual-studio-code-ctrl-tab-not-working-as-it-was-used-to) but my configuration already contains those entries:

[image]

Does anyone know why this might be? Is one of those other settings clashing with the one I want?

Interesting to note is that `ctrl` + `shift` + `tab` is working as normal